# MS Teams. Cannot login anymore as guest, still works in my old laptop though

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have this strange issue with Teams.
First of all let me give you quick background. I am external IT for a company, I have setup complete MS365 tenant for them, I have admin access to MS365. I also have my own professional email address (GSuite) and had invited myself as guest to Teams. So far so good, Teams running fine in my laptop and phone for over two years.
I bought a new laptop and tried to login to Teams, password accepted but Teams stuck on loading, both in desktop app and in online (MS Edge) browser version. I tried in sandbox, I tried in inPrivate window, nothing, Teams stuck at loading. I cleared cache, cleared credentials but no luck.
I have tried every possible trick, I have raised support from MS365 admin portal, MS employee connected to my laptop and verified the issue but couldn't really find solution.
In my old laptop Teams still works, no problem there.
Could anyone else possible think of any other solution or trick? I would really appreciate that.